# how do I remove the first instance of a regex capture group from strings in a pandas series?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to remove the first instance of a regex capture group from a series of strings in pandas, the inverse of `pandas.Series.str.extract`. This works fine with `extract` in the following code, where I extract the first word that begins with a double underscore:

```
import pandas as pd

regex = r"^(?:.*?)(__\S+)"

t = pd.Series(['no match', '__match at start', 'match __in_the middle', 'the end __matches', 'string __with two __captures'])
t.str.extract(regex)
```

```
           0
0        NaN
1    __match
2   __in_the
3  __matches
4     __with
dtype: object
```

but if I do `pandas.Series.str.replace` with an empty string then it replaces the noncapturing group as well:

```py
t.str.replace(regex, '')
```

```
0        no match
1        at start
2          middle
3
4  two __captures
dtype: object
```

How do I get the following output?

```
0                no match
1                at start
2           match  middle
3                the end
4  string  two __captures
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
t.str.replace(r'^(.*?)__\S+', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Or:

```py
t.str.replace(r'__\S+', '', n=1, regex=True)
```

See the [`Series.str.replace` documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

> Replace each occurrence of pattern/regex in the Series/Index.
> ...
> **nint, default -1 (all)**
>      Number of replacements to make from start.

Output:

```
0         no match
1         at start
2    match  middle
3         the end 
dtype: object
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `__` - two underscores
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, and the text it matches is still consumed (i.e. added to the match value and is thus affected during the regex replace operation). "Non-capturing" does not mean "non-matching".

The `\1` in the replacement pattern is the *[replacement backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)* that refers to the text captured into capturing group 1.

The point is that we capture into a group and restore with a backreference used in the replacement pattern the text that we want to keep. The text we want to replace/remove is just matched, not captured.

Comment: sorry, my question wasn't complete. I need to remove only the first instance of the capture group, but your regex will replace all instances of it. I edited the question

Comment: accepting this because it was first and the edited solution with the noncapturing group works, but can you add an explanation for `r'\1'` in your solution? I don't understand it at all. Also, why does `r'^(.*?)__\S+'` work but not `r'^(.*?)(__\S+)'`?

Comment: @shortorian I added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

According to pandas's [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) you can specify the number of replacements you want to to make from start. If it works anything like Python's re.sub then you can use @Wiktor Stribiżew code with one modification

```
t.str.replace(r'__\S+', '', 1, regex=True)
```

If this not how things work in pandas then

```
for s in t:
    x = re.sub(r"__\S+", "", s, 1)
```